# How to get access log of PAC(proxy auto config)

Tags: javascript, logging, browser, pac

I'm using Chrome, and I want monitor brower access log for myself ( I suspect some extension send url in background, etc ), I try to use Privoxy, but it can't logging HTTPS url

I think PAC is the only way for logging original url, I use PAC for few years, but I still don't know how to debug it or logging access. How I can do it ? (or any way to logging original url)

I guess some code:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {

    /*
     logging variable 'url' there, but how to write it to file or somewhere ?

     // some logging code

     */

    if (0
        || shExpMatch(url, "*facebook*")
        || shExpMatch(url, "*google.com/*")
        || shExpMatch(url, "*twitter/*")

    ) {
        return "SOCKS5 127.0.0.1:55777; SOCKS5 127.0.0.1:55888";
    }

    return "DIRECT";
}
```

Comment: PAC is just a simple ECMAScript. Google "http debug" and you can find LOTS of logging/debugging tools.

Comment: Do you known what's the different between "http logging" and "pac logging" ? you can't monitor https url in http debug tool, I said I used Privoxy, just like Fiddler or other proxy tool. and "alert" or "console.log" no effect in Chrome PAC ("alert" can be used in Firefox), what's your __LOTS__ of ? Can you enumerate just one of them ?

Comment: `alert` is a function under `window`, which doesn't exists in PAC's environment. And that's true for most familiar functions you use in web development. From your question I see that you only want to log `URL`, and, I'm not sure about Provixy, but Fiddler definitely has the ability to do that (it even has the ability to decrypt your SSL connection, if you configure it correctly; [Official site](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/OptionsUI.asp)).